# Archive Build iOS App with XCode Open

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, ad-hoc-distribution

I am currently able to adhoc build my iOS app using the following command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -configuration AdHoc archive -archivePath /Users/andrewherrick/Desktop/MyApp.xcarchive
```

It works great when my phone isn't connected to my Mac having XCode recognize it. However, when it's plugged in it always bombs out:

```
Reason: You cannot archive for the iOS Simulator platform.
```

Is there anyway I can modify the build command to allow me to NOT have to disconnect my phone everytime I want a fresh adhoc build?

Comment: Did you figure out ?

Comment: Nope still disconnecting phone during build :(

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this, I couldn't figure out why my archive command suddenly stopped working!

Comment: I have the same issue and would be interested by a solution as well :/

Answer (score 12):

try using the -destination parameter. e.g.:

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -configuration AdHoc archive -archivePath /Users/andrewherrick/Desktop/MyApp.xcarchive -destination generic/platform=iOS
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have fixed the issue for me.